# Cannot update imageButton from inside adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I want to change the image of the imagebutton when I click on it. This imageButton is part of layout out file which I have inflated in my custom adapter which feeds a kind of card view (Image with few buttons) to my main container layout.

I have added the imagebutton listener in my CustomAdapter.java:

```
cardHolder.mLikeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Log.i("Sushil", "clicked like button!!!!!");
updateHeartButton(true);
}
});
```

When I click on the button, my listener is called and from inside I call a method to update the image of button:

```
private void updateHeartButton(boolean animated) {
cardHolder.mLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_red);
}
```

But the imagebutton does not get updated with new image. can someone help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since cardHolder changes (part of the adapter `getView()`, the last cardHolder will be called rather the one which was tapped.

Please change your code as follow and try again:

```
cardHolder.mLikeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("Sushil", "clicked like button!!!!!");
        ((ImageButton) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_red);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
cardHolder.mLikeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  cardHolder.mLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_red);
}
});
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: your holder class hold button object per each listView item, when  you change  holder attribute your listView item changed because when your convertView  is null  you calling `cardHolder.getTag()`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_red);`

Or in other way if you need to go back to the previous image when clicking back on it:

You can create a btn.xml file in the drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/like_selected"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/like_normal"/>

</selector>
```

In your xml for the button you set this xml to the background:

```
android:background="@drawable/btn"
```

In your updateHeartButton() method you can use:

```
cardHolder.mLikeButton.setSelected(true)
```